# The rule does not exist as a registered rule

Tags: extension

I am trying to use the ncn-civi-zoom extension. When going to an admin path for the extension ([civicrm/Zoom/zoomaccounts](https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom/blob/master/xml/Menu/ncn_civi_zoom.xml)) I get a "QuickForm Error: the rule does not exist as a registered rule."

I have traced the issue to this file for the form https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom/blob/master/CRM/NcnCiviZoom/Form/Settings.php#L194

I am not sure however how to know what rule is the problem and how to go about fixing this.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you file an issue at https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom/issues ? That would be the first step

Comment: That version has not been updated since the removal of JWT authentication.  You need the 'alternative' version: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/ncn-civi-zoom